# how to remove 4 dots near the signal symbol in the above of my navigation bar?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, iphone-x

[image]

I only have this issue in my iPhoneX, as we can see in the picture above, in the top right corner, in the left side of signal icon we can see 4 dots.

but in the iphone 6 like the picture below and other, I have no issue for this
[image]

I don't think I give a setting and autolayout for that section. I only give this code in the appdelegate to make the signal, time and battery icon to be white

in appdelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // to make status bar in the light mode (in info.plist it also has to be set 'View controller-based status bar appearance' to NO)

        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent


        return true
    }
```

I want to remove that 4 dots, how to do that?

Comment: There's nothing to remove. That's not from your app. That is where the signal strength bars appear on a real iPhone X. The simulator just shows the dots.

Comment: Look at this [sample video](https://images.apple.com/media/ww/iphone-x/2017/01df5b43-28e4-4848-bf20-490c34a926a7/overview/primary/design_gestures/large.mp4), shared by Apple, for an actual visual area on real device, at place of dots.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not an issue. That’s usually where the cellular signal strength is displayed. In case you don't have any signal it will show just four dots, as [mentioned here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253021952).